# How to fix error "'recipe for target "doc/automake-1.14.1' failed" while building Xenomai

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, automake, buildroot

I am building Xenomai 2 on a Kernel version 3 with buildroot. Buildroot ist done. Now I am trying to compile it with the "make" command. When I try to compile with the "make" command it appears a failure: recipe for target 'doc/automake-1.14.1' failed. Any help how I can solve that problem?

Ubuntu already has automake version 1.15.1. So I don't really know why it is making the 1.14.1 version while building. Can I change that somewhere?
I have also tried to install the 1.14.1 version but that did not work because it did not find that version, although I have downloaded it...

Here is the cmd-window output:

`````````````````
  GEN      doc/automake-1.14.1
help2man: can't get `--help' info from automake-1.14
Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
Makefile:3707: recipe for target 'doc/automake-1.14.1' failed
make[1]: *** [doc/automake-1.14.1] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/daniel/Desktop/ccode/Daniel/buildroot-2014.08/output/build/host-automake-1.14.1'
package/pkg-generic.mk:177: recipe for target '/home/daniel/Desktop/ccode/Daniel/buildroot-2014.08/output/build/host-automake-1.14.1/.stamp_built' failed
make: *** [/home/daniel/Desktop/ccode/Daniel/buildroot-2014.08/output/build/host-automake-1.14.1/.stamp_built] Error 2

````````````````
`````````````````

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed on September 11, 2014 by commit [2020ddbd0f2c32863e6be69a235852a088744c28](https://git.buildroot.org/buildroot/commit/?id=2020ddbd0f2c32863e6be69a235852a088744c28). Please use an up-to-date version of Buildroot.